# How to take multiple cells and input them separately into one location?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time posting, so go easy. I'm also new to using the macro function in excel.

I have a cell (C1) that when input with an asset ID calculations depreciation for multiple years. The asset IDs are all listed from C12:C3981. I'm trying to find a way to take the asset ID listed in C12, place it in C1 then copy a range and place it in J12 (or the J column of whatever C asset was placed in C1). I have a code that does it manually, but I have to type in the C values. Is there anyway to select say C12 through C3981 and have them input into C1 individually with their J values copy and pasted automatically?

Here is what I'm using now which is quite cumbersome.

```
Range("C1").Value = "=C14"
Range("J10:AA10").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("J14").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("C1").Value = "=C15"
Range("J10:AA10").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("J15").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick (I tested it):

```
For idx = 12 To 3981
  Range("C1").Value = "=C" & CStr(idx)
  Range("J10:AA10").Select
  Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
  Selection.Copy
  Range("J" & CStr(idx)).Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next idx
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you so much. You have made my life 1000x easier.